# My Backbone Model's validate method called on model.fetch, but not on collection.fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

**EDIT tl;dr:** *I would like to only fetch models and add them to the collection that meet some validation criteria. I am able to use the `model.validate()` method if I am fetching only a single model, but when using `collection.fetch()`, `model.validate()` is not called.*

I am using the github gist API to make a gist fallery, a la bl.ocks.org. I would only like to display gists that have a "tags" file, so I have a validate method on my Gist Model:

```
class Gist extends Backbone.Model

  validate: (attrs, options)->
    if attrs.files.hasOwnProperty("tags") is false
      return "no tags file"

  sync: (method, model, options) ->
    options.timeout = 8000
    options.dataType = 'jsonp'
    options.validate = true
    return Backbone.sync(method, model, options)

  defaults: ......
  parse: (data)-> ......
```

This works correctly when I fetch a single gist from github. However, when I am fetching a collection of gists, this validate method is not fired.

```
class Gists extends Backbone.Collection

  model: Gist

  sync: (method, model,options) ->
    options || options = {}
    options.timeout = 8000
    options.dataType = 'jsonp'
    options.validate = true
    return Backbone.sync(method, model, options)

  parse: (response) ->
    response.data

  #more methods here, including initialize, comparator, and custom ones
```

The behavior I have now is that when I am displaying the list of gists, i get thumbnails for gists that do not have the "tags" file (see screenshot below). However, when I click on a thumbnail with an invalid gist, it won't display because there is a `validationError` returned from the `validate` method (The gist model's`fetch` method is called when a thumbnail is clicked to get additional information from github before it is rendered)

[image]

How can I use the model's `validate` method to make sure the model is not added to the collection via `collection.fetch` if it doesn't have a tags file?

Comment: Use a parser (parse function) at collection to filter out unwanted model.

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. I realize now that something more insidious was going on with `backbone-fetch-cache.` On first page load the models were correctly validated, and only on subsequent refreshes were invalid models shown. But useing collection.parse got around that.

Answer (score 0):

Ravi Hamsa's suggestion worked beautifully. Here is how I implemented it:

```
class Gists extends Backbone.Collection

  model: GistModel

  sync: (method, model,options) ->
    options || options = {}
    options.timeout = 8000
    options.dataType = 'jsonp'
    return Backbone.sync(method, model, options)

  parse: (response) ->
    (gist for gist in response.data when gist.files.hasOwnProperty("tags") is true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Backbone has a function called parse, that is called when any data is returned from server before backbone bind the content from server to model.
You can override this function, something like this.

```
Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function () {
        return {
            id: this.get("id"),
            AnotherThing: this.get("AnotherThing")
        }
    }
});
```

Take a read here.

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse

Hope it helps.